# AutoComplete on Object

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I found this code that works like I want it but I need to filter the Name property on the object and display the object properties when selected. I forked this.
http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/

My attempt... that isn't working. It is probably something simple. Isn't it always. Appreciate other eyes to figure this out.
https://jsfiddle.net/lnbailey/7py3rbgh/2/

```
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
  <div ng-controller='autocompleteController'>
    <input auto-complete ui-items="trans" ng-model="selected"> Name = {{selected}}
    <div ng-repeat="name in names">
      <div ng-if="selected == name">
        {{selected.Name}}<br> 
        {{selected.Address}}<br>
        {{selected.City}} <br>
        {{selected.State}} <br>
        {{selected.Zip}}        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div

function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.names = [{
    'id': 1,
    'Name': 'Transporter 1',
    'Address': '1 Transporter Address',
    'City': "Nashville",
    'State': 'TN',
    'Zip': "10001",
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'Name': 'Transporter 2',
    'Address': '2 Transporter Address',
    'City': "Nashville",
    'State': 'TN',
    'Zip': "10001",
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'Name': 'Transporter 3',
    'Address': '3 Transporter Address',
    'City': "Nashville",
    'State': 'TN',
    'Zip': "10001",
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'Name': 'Transporter 4',
    'Address': '4 Transporter Address',
    'City': "Nashville",
    'State': 'TN',
    'Zip': "10001",
  }, {
    'id': 5,
    'Name': 'Transporter 5',
    'Address': '5 Transporter Address',
    'City': "Nashville",
    'State': 'TN',
    'Zip': "10001",
  }
  ];

  $scope.trans = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.names, function(name) {
    $scope.trans.push(name.first);
  });
};

angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
  return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    iElement.autocomplete({
      source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
      select: function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          iElement.trigger('input');
        }, 0);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bootstrap typehead with angular in the recommended way,

**DEMO**

```js
angular
  .module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    //ngModel value
    $scope.selected = undefined;
    //lookup values
    $scope.names = [{
      'id': 1,
      'Name': 'Transporter 1',
      'Address': '1 Transporter Address',
      'City': "Nashville",
      'State': 'TN',
      'Zip': "10001",
    }, {
      'id': 2,
      'Name': 'Transporter 2',
      'Address': '2 Transporter Address',
      'City': "Nashville",
      'State': 'TN',
      'Zip': "10001",
    }, {
      'id': 3,
      'Name': 'Transporter 3',
      'Address': '3 Transporter Address',
      'City': "Nashville",
      'State': 'TN',
      'Zip': "10001",
    }, {
      'id': 4,
      'Name': 'Transporter 4',
      'Address': '4 Transporter Address',
      'City': "Nashville",
      'State': 'TN',
      'Zip': "10001",
    }, {
      'id': 5,
      'Name': 'Transporter 5',
      'Address': '5 Transporter Address',
      'City': "Nashville",
      'State': 'TN',
      'Zip': "10001",
    }];
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h4>Custom templates for results</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="country as country.Name for country in names | filter:{Name:$viewValue}" class="form-control" typeahead-show-hint="true" typeahead-min-length="0">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea. I found that solution and it does work well. However, this project can't have bootstrap. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of issues with your fiddle, but there may have been a small typo or something because it didn't work until I retyped a few things. But I have a simplified version working here: http://jsfiddle.net/davi3blu3/d0zrohbg/2/

A couple of notes:
The controller function name didn't match the controller directive, 'DefaultCtrl' vs 'autocompleteController'.

In your ng-repeat, there was {{ selected.Name }} which was the value from your input, and not referring to your array in $scope.  Changed to {{ name.Name }}.

I had better luck using 'ng-show' instead of 'ng-if'.

I added a filter to the ng-repeat to use the search term as it is typed.

Hope that's helpful!

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
<div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>

    <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected">
    Name = {{selected}}

    <div ng-repeat="name in names | filter:selected">
        <p>{{name.name}}</p>
        <p>{{name.city}}</p>  
        <p>{{name.state}}</p>  
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
$scope.names = [
    {
    "name": "andrea",
    "city": "louisville",
    "state": "ky"
  },
  {
    "name": "bill",
    "city": "cleveland",
    "state": "oh"
  },
  {
    "name": "charlie",
    "city": "nashville",
    "state": "tn"
  },
  {
    "name": "daniel",
    "city": "boston",
    "state": "ma"
  },
  {
    "name": "elizabeth",
    "city": "philadelphia",
    "state": "pa"
  },
  {
    "name": "francis",
    "city": "alexandria",
    "state": "va"
  },
  {
    "name": "greg",
    "city": "lexington",
    "state": "ky"
  }
    ];
}

angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
  return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    iElement.autocomplete({
      source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
      select: function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          iElement.trigger('input');
        }, 0);
      }
    });
  };
});
```